# How do I rebuild a broken Eberron construct?

Tags: dnd-5e, crafting, eberron

I’m playing a Warforged monk who has an affinity for small, cute things. So, On a mission, we came across a halfling automaton. Its programming was too ingrained and we had to break it. I may have stolen the body.

Is there a way for me to fix it and use it as a playable character/companion? How would I go about doing that? And what’s it going to cost me?

Comment: Welcome to the site! In order to answer your question we need to know what game your playing as this site handles a wide range of RPGs. If you are playing a game with multiple editions we need to know which edition as well. Take our [tour] for more information on how things work here (and to earn a free badge). Happy stacking!

Comment: Agreed. We need to know which rules you're using to answer this correctly. You can edit the question tags, the question itself, or both, to provide that information. And welcome to the site!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, only one minor quibble remained—system information should go in the tags. I’ve added [[tag:dnd-5e]], and voted to reopen the question. Shouldn’t be long! Thanks for bearing with us as we got things in order.

Comment: Are you looking for homebrewed or raw solutions? Have you asked your dm?

Comment: @GarretGang The question originally had the [[tag:rules-as-written]] tag, which was removed for dubious, but well-established, reasons. Presumably, at least, official rules are desired.

Comment: What is an 'automaton' in this context? Is there an official stat block in a book somewhere, or is this just something the DM came up with?

Comment: DM is doing his own research. He pulled it from the monster manual but it looks like you can choose to be a construct for games. But I’m looking for the book solution because I can’t seem to find a table that shows fixing or creating stats for such a creature.  This Automaton is a clockwork construct.

Answer (score 5):

## Have House Cannith do it

There are no RAW as far as I could find, so everything listed below is up to your DM, but here is my interpretation based on the Eberron setting and the currently released material for Eberron.

In Eberron, almost all constructs and such are made by house Cannith or one of their licensed workshops. So if you have a broken automaton it would be logical to go to he nearest house workshop/enclave and inquire about repair services.

The fact that you also need to reset its programming only enforces this need to find an expert, as simply fixing all the broken parts would mean you would get the same ingrained enemy as you already defeated.

Determining cost is hard, and can be up to the DM, but I would suggest that the House requests a service instead of gold. This could be anything from looking for rare materials needed for the repairs to a job Cannith needs doing that they see as equivalently valuable.

If you want to do it yourself, or avoid House Cannith, you could try some tinkering tool checks to fix it and at least one very hard check to fix its programming. You could instead find an independent Artificer and hope he/she has the skills for the job.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously it's GM's discretion but I would say since it's relatively small a tinker's tool check would be applicable? If not smith's tools perhaps

I doubt there is anything RAW on this so it would be a conversation with your GM. If he wants to make it more difficult and interesting there could be a quest to find a power source, heart or brain for it.

If he makes it hard for you hopefully it will be a useful item when it's repaired :)

Comment: Can you support your view on this? This reads much more like an opinion and not something supported by either how you've run it/had it run at a table or by looking at the current rules options. We do look for answers to [be backed up](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8696/what-are-the-citation-expectations-of-answers-on-rpg-stack-exchange) - it's a big difference between the stack and a standard forum.